# Renaming a container/folder in azure blob storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to rename a container name for users when a condition is  met. I made some research and found out that there is no rename function for containers in azure blob storage. But there is a way to accomplish this by copying the files and deleting it after copy. Below is the code I made.

```
        string ContainerName = "old-container-name-user1";
        string NewContainerName = "new-container-name-user2"

        CloudStorageAccount sourceAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        CloudBlobClient sourceblobClient = sourceAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer sourceBlobContainer = sourceblobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);

        CloudBlobContainer destBlobContainer = sourceblobClient.GetContainerReference(NewContainerName);

        CloudBlockBlob blobOriginal = sourceBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(ContainerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blobNew = destBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(NewContainerName);

        blobNew.StartCopy(blobOriginal);
        blobOriginal.Delete();
```

When I execute this code I got an error message. Below is the error.

> Exception User-Unhandled
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException:'The remote server
>   returned an error: (404) Not Found.'
>
> Inner Exception WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   (404) Not Found.

When I also try "blobNew.StartCopyAsync(blobOriginal)" the code just goes through but when I check the containers in azure there is no container created. What do you think the problem is? Any tips on how to improve my code? Delete function does not work also.

**UPDATE**
I update my code and was able to copy the files from other to container to the new one. Below is the code.

```
string ContainerName = "old-container-name-user1"
string NewContainerName = "new-container-name-user2"
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);
CloudBlobContainer destcontainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(NewContainerName);
destcontainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob);
IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> IE = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
foreach (IListBlobItem item in IE)
{
    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
    CloudBlockBlob destBlob = destcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name);
    destBlob.StartCopyAsync(new Uri(GetSharedAccessUri(blob.Name, container)));
}
```

**AccessURI Method**

```
 private static string GetSharedAccessUri(string blobName, CloudBlobContainer container)
    {
        DateTime toDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
            SharedAccessStartTime = null,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = new DateTimeOffset(toDateTime)
        };

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        string sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
        return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas;
    }
```

Now its working but another problem shows up. It says

> System.InvalidCastException:  'Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory' to type
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob'.'

But this will be posted in another question. Thanks to our friend Gauriv for pointing out my problem. Check his answer below.

**Update 2**

By adding `useFlatBlobListing: true` in `IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> IE = container.ListBlobs(blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.Metadata);` I was able to fix my problem. This line of code was put in my display.

Final Code

```
        IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> IE = container.ListBlobs(blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.Metadata, useFlatBlobListing: true);
```

Comment: `StartCopy` method will copy a blob from source container to destination container. You're specifying the container's name as blob name and that's why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your code for creating source and destination blob:

```
    CloudBlockBlob blobOriginal = sourceBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(ContainerName);
    CloudBlockBlob blobNew = destBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(NewContainerName);
```

You'll notice that you're passing the names of the blob container and not the name of the blob. Because you don't have a blob in the container by the name of the container, you're getting 404 error.

---

To copy a blob container, what you have to do is list all blobs from the source container and then copy them individually in the destination container. Once all the blobs have been copied, you can delete the source container.

If you want, you can use Microsoft's Storage Explorer to achieve "rename container" functionality. It also works by copying blobs from old container to the renamed container and then deletes the old container.

---

```
    static void RenameContainer()
    {
        var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key";
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var sourceContainer = client.GetContainerReference("source-container");
        var targetContainer = client.GetContainerReference("target-container");
        targetContainer.CreateIfNotExists();//Create target container
        BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listing blobs. Please wait...");
            var blobsResult = sourceContainer.ListBlobsSegmented(prefix: "", useFlatBlobListing: true, blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.All, maxResults: 1000, currentToken: continuationToken, options: new BlobRequestOptions(), operationContext: new OperationContext());
            continuationToken = blobsResult.ContinuationToken;
            var items = blobsResult.Results;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var blob = (CloudBlob)item;
                var targetBlob = targetContainer.GetBlobReference(blob.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Copying \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" blob container to \"{2}\" blob container.", blob.Name, sourceContainer.Name, targetContainer.Name));

                targetBlob.StartCopy(blob.Uri);
            }
        } while (continuationToken != null);
        Console.WriteLine("Deleting source blob container. Please wait.");
        //sourceContainer.DeleteIfExists();
        Console.WriteLine("Rename container operation complete. Press any key to terminate the application.");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Now It make sense. Is there a way I can change it using code? I wanted to change the container name once a user click a certain button.Microsoft Storage Explorer seems like a tool. @Gaurav Mantri

Comment: Gaurav, I made some small changes to your code. Is there a way to change the metadata["Filename"] of a file? In certain cases I want to rename a file and metadata filename of a file if a specific file was uploaded or copied. For example this pdf was named "source-container.pdf" before after excution I want it to name to "target-container.pdf".

Comment: I add  this in the foreach condition of yours. 

if (blob.Metadata["Filename"].Contains("source-container"))
                {
                    blob.Metadata["Filename"] = blob.Metadata["Filename"].Replace("source-container", "target-container");
                    targetBlob.SetMetadata();
                }

Comment: Problem is after I changed I received this error. Exception Details: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: Can you please ask a separate question for this? Do include the code you're using and the issue you're running into.

Comment: Got it man. Im sorry. Ill send you a link after I created it. Thank you.

Comment: Appreciate it. Thank you for your understanding. Please share the link once you've posted the new question.

Comment: Guarav. Here is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59152885/changing-metadatafilename-of-blob-and-container-when-copying-and-deleting-co

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look. BTW, answered this question of yours as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150291/system-invalidcastexception-in-renaming-azure-container.

Answer (score -2):

You can rename containers with Microsoft's "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer" (after version 0.8.3).

**Actual Answer:** 
Regarding your error message, If the client application receives an HTTP 404 (Not found) message from the server, this means that the object the client was attempting to use does not exist in the storage service. There are several possible reasons for this, such as:

·         The client or another process previously deleted the object (Make sure name is correct)

·         A Shared Access Signature (SAS) authorization issue

·         Client-side code does not have permission to access the object

·         Network failure

In order to identify the issue in detail, you can add a try/catch and see the actual error

Comment: If you look at the error, it is 404 error i.e. not found. Also, where in the code do you see SAS being used? Same thing goes with your comment about JS...Code is C#.

Comment: Those are possible causes :) , thanks for correcting it

Comment: No, they’re not. That’s why I mentioned them.

Comment: I wonder what is different . Same thing I mentioned in my answer