# System.InvalidCastException in Renaming Azure Container

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to rename a container in azure blob storage. I was able to successfully rename the container. But I noticed in some few cases that during some process. I encountered some error.

Here is the error message.

> System.InvalidCastException:  'Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory' to type
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob'.'

Below is my code.

```
string ContainerName = "old-container-name";
    string NewContainerName = "new-container-name";
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);
    CloudBlobContainer destcontainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(NewContainerName);
    destcontainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob);
    IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> IE = container.ListBlobs(blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.Metadata);
    foreach (IListBlobItem item in IE)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
        CloudBlockBlob destBlob = destcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name);
        destBlob.StartCopyAsync(new Uri(GetSharedAccessUri(blob.Name, container)));
    }
```

I received the error on this line:

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
```

Do you guys have a fix on this one? Any tips on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because of the way you're listing the blobs.

```
IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> IE = container.ListBlobs(blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.Metadata);
```

Above line of code will list both blobs and virtual folders. Virtual folders are represented by `CloudBlobDirectory`. Since you're trying to cast an object of type `CloudBlockBlob` as `CloudBlobDirectory`, you're getting this exception.

To list all blobs in a blob container, please use the following override of `ListBlobs` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azure-dotnet-legacy.

You will need to pass `true` for `useFlatBlobListing` parameter. It will then return only the blobs and not virtual folders.

Comment: Got it Gaurav. This was the one causing problem. I added the useFlatBlobListing without removing the old one and its working fine now. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

- Check the type of `item` before casting.
- You must `await` your `Task`.
- Always prefer the Async API. Don't mix non-Async and Async APIs (this does mean using the custom `ListBlobsAsync` method also defined below as there is no single `ListBlobsAsync` method):

```
async Task CopyBlobsAsync()
{
    const String ContainerName    = "old-container-name";
    const String NewContainerName = "new-container-name";

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse( CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString") );
    CloudBlobClient     blobClient     = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer  container      = blobClient.GetContainerReference( ContainerName );
    CloudBlobContainer  destcontainer  = blobClient.GetContainerReference( NewContainerName );

    await destcontainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync( BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob );

    List<IListBlobItem> blobs = await ListBlobsAsync( container ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    List<Task>          tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach( IListBlobItem item in blobs )
    {
        if( item is CloudBlockBlob blob )
        {
            CloudBlockBlob destBlob = destcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference( blob.Name );
            Uri destUri = new Uri( GetSharedAccessUri( blob.Name, container ) );
            Task task = destBlob.StartCopyAsync( destUri  );
            tasks.Add( task );
        }
    }

    await Task.WhenAll( tasks ).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// From https://ahmet.im/blog/azure-listblobssegmentedasync-listcontainerssegmentedasync-how-to/
async Task<List<IListBlobItem> ListBlobsAsync( CloudBlobContainer container )
{
    BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    List<IListBlobItem> results = new List<IListBlobItem>();
    do
    {
        var response = await ListBlobsSegmentedAsync( continuationToken );
        continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
        results.AddRange( response.Results );
    }
    while( continuationToken != null );
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Dai. I use your code and change mine. I noticed some few lines that I am not familiar with. First is this one

ListBlobsSegmentedAsync the vs compiler does read this one and suggested to create a method. Also, the if (item is CloudBlockBlob blob) the compiler says it is not available in c# 5 it is suggesting to upgrade my version. Last one is the .CreateIfNotExistsAsync(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob) it says Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.WindowzAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobContainerPublicAccessType' to 'System.Threading.CancellationToken'.

Comment: @KevinJacob What version of Visual Studio are you using? What version of the C# language is your project configured to use? What Azure Storage library package (full name) and version are you using?

Comment: Its c# 5 and the azure storage we are using is i am not sure but here is our azure storage snippet in web.config. <dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="*******" culture="neutral" /> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.4.0.0" newVersion="8.4.0.0" /> </dependentAssembly>

Comment: @KevinJacob Ah - C# 5.0 is from 2012 (we're on C# 8.0 now) and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` is also outdated (we're at version 10 now). My code is for version 10 with C# 7.3. Is there a reason you're using very outdated tooling?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes Dai. I am kind of working on an old source code.

Comment: @KevinJacob Working on an old code-base is fine (my current project is a WebForms application from 2012) - but there shouldn't be anything stopping you from upgrading the C# language version and NuGet dependencies beyond fixing issues caused by breaking-changes.

Comment: I see. I'll apply your code. Dai. Thanks for answering all of my questions. Greatly appreciated!