# Changing Metadata["Filename"] of blob and Container when copying and deleting container

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to change the container name and specific files inside of it when a certain condition was met. The 1st code below works fine. It can change the container name and blob.name correctly. The issue is the 2nd code below.

Below is my code.

```
string ContainerName = "old-container-name";
        string NewContainerName = "new-container-name";
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var sourcecontainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);
        var destcontainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(NewContainerName);
        destcontainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob);
        BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        do
        {
            var blobsResult = sourcecontainer.ListBlobsSegmented(prefix: "", useFlatBlobListing: true, blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.All, maxResults: 1000, currentToken: continuationToken, options: new BlobRequestOptions(), operationContext: new OperationContext());
            continuationToken = blobsResult.ContinuationToken;
            var items = blobsResult.Results;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                string newName = "";
                var blob = (CloudBlob)item;
                if (blob.Name.Contains("originalfilename"))
                    newName = blob.Name.Replace("originalfilename", "newfilename");
                else
                    newName = blob.Name;

                var targetBlob = destcontainer.GetBlobReference(newName);
                targetBlob.StartCopy(blob.Uri);
            }
        }
        while (continuationToken != null);
        sourcecontainer.DeleteIfExists();
```

Before I added this condition inside the code above.

```
        if (blob.Metadata["Filename"].Contains("originalfilename"))
        {
            blob.Metadata["Filename"] = blob.Metadata["Filename"].Replace("originalfilename", "newfilename");
            targetBlob.SetMetadata();
        }
```

I was able to change the metadata["filename"] of the file but I encountered an error while retrieving the files which before is not happening. I think the way I update the Metadata was wrong.

Below is the error message:

> Exception Details: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException:
>   The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Any tips on how to fix this one or a better way to change the metadata?

Comment: Does your blob's metadata contains a key by the name `Filename`?

Comment: Yes we did add metadata by using this snippet.

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + filename);
                        blockBlob.Metadata.Add("Filename", filename);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, `Filename` is not an inbuilt metadata of blob. The inbuilt one is `Name`, which you cannot change. It always equals to the blob's name.

So, just as @Gaurav Mantri said in comment, did you add a `Filename` metadata for each blob manually?

If you have added `Filename` metadata for your blobs, then you can get and update it as following:

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        string connString = "your_connection_string";
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("pub");
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("CP4.png");

        // Important, you need to fetch all attributes first! 
        cloudBlockBlob.FetchAttributes();

        if (cloudBlockBlob.Metadata.ContainsKey("Filename"))
        {

            Console.WriteLine(cloudBlockBlob.Metadata["Filename"].ToString());
            cloudBlockBlob.Metadata["Filename"] = "123";
            cloudBlockBlob.SetMetadata();
        }
        else
        {
            cloudBlockBlob.Metadata.Add("Filename", "CP4.png");
            cloudBlockBlob.SetMetadata();
        }
    }
```

In my test, the `CP4.png` blob's `Filename` metadata was updated to `123`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jack for asnwering. Yes we did add metadata by using this snippet. CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + filename); blockBlob.Metadata.Add("Filename", filename);

Comment: Thanks for the tips and code jack. My code is working fine now. Thank you very much man.